# How to create a new homegroup deleting the existing one, without the help of the computer that created it, on windows 10(1607)?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, home-networking, homegroup

I am well aware of the similar kind of questions existing on this page. Though the answers that were presented either did not match my situation or did not satisfy my needs. **I'm on Windows 10(1607)**.

My brother had already created a *homegroup* on his computer of which my computer is a part too. Currently, his computer is not available for use. I don't remember the password of that homegroup too.

I want to create a new homegroup. Or modify the existing homegroup. Or delete the existing homegroup?

Answers highly appreciated.

Comment: there is no Windows 10.1. There are Version 1507, 1511, 1607 and 1703. Which do you use?

Comment: Okay. It is 1607.